# Neato not found with pygraphviz on Mac OS

Tags: python, textmate, graphviz

I have a weird little problem.

When I run:

```
import pygraphviz as pgv
a = pgv.AGraph() 
print a._get_prog('neato')
```

I get:

```
ValueError: 'Program neato not found in path.'
```

However, when I do `neato -V` in a terminal:

```
$ neato -V
neato - graphviz version 2.28.0 (20120301.1344)
```

What's the deal here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I'm answering this question rather quickly, but rather than deleting it, I'll add some text so that the next person might find it. The problem wasn't **pygraphviz** at all, but **Textmate 2.x** being a bit weird about the `PATH`. It seems that textmate uses its own path, but you can't find this variable in the variable editor. However, you can *append* to it, using the normal syntax, as shown below. This fixed `pygraphviz.test()` for me too.

[image: What I had to do]